# Raspberry with sour taste?

Tags: raspberries

I noticed that some raspberries are very tasty and sour but others taste sweet (which I don't like), and it is hard for me to know which it is by looking at them. Their size seem to correlate with this so I try to get small raspberries, but this does not always work.

I heard that the ones that taste sweet are usually a refined species, and that wild raspberries taste better.

I wonder if there is some raspberry kind that is known to be sour. Maybe I can try to remember their name and look in that case.

Comment: Assuming you mean red raspberries , the sweet ones are likely more ripe. Yellow and black raspberries are less sour/ more sweet than reds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A raspberry native to the US that can be relatively sour is the [black cap raspberry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubus_occidentalis), *Rubus occidentalis*. Their fruit is smaller than a domestic raspberry. In my area of the US, the canes are only 3 ft (1m) high and very prickly. The canes often grow wild either in in open woods or, more commonly, as "edge" plants at the border between woods and field. In a domestic setting they can be invasive, as they spread underground to create a prickly thicket.

Comment: Do you think they are available in Europe? Is it popular in food industry?

Comment: I don't think they're popular in the food industry, but the berries make an excellent jam or jelly. I have found one reference to their occurring as a naturalized plant in Central Europe (https://www.researchgate.net/publication/272476284_Rubus_occidentalis_Rosaceae_-_A_new_naturalized_raspberry_species_in_the_Polish_flora). This probably means that it's being cultivated in those areas as well. Given its reputed health benefits, you may be able to find it in some specialized nurseries.

Comment: @Emil Note that blackcaps have a different flavor, though. They taste kind of like black cherry Shasta, and they're about that sour. Most kinds get one crop per season.

Comment: Allright. I did find some autumn raspberries that are supposed to be sour as well after searching for black raspberries so maybe they are a better fit for me.